# Log4j2 not working in spring boot (proogramtic approach)

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-boot

**How to disable default spring logback configuration and configure log4j2 in programmatic way?**

**1. configure in listener**

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration > builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setStatusLevel( Level.ERROR);
    builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
    // create a console appender
    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
        ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
    appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
        .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
    builder.add( appenderBuilder );
    // create a rolling file appender
    LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
        .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");
    ComponentBuilder<?> triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
        .addComponent(builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?"))
        .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "100M"));
    appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
        .addAttribute("fileName", "target/rolling.log")
        .addAttribute("filePattern", "target/archive/rolling-%d{MM-dd-yy}.log.gz")
        .add(layoutBuilder)
        .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
    // create the new logger
    builder.add( builder.newLogger( "TestLogger", Level.DEBUG )
        .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) )
        .addAttribute( "additivity", false ) );

    builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( Level.DEBUG )
        .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) ) );
    Configurator.initialize(builder.build());

}
```

I want **configure log4j2 in spring boot in programmatic way** and **add size based trigger policy** and **time based trigger policy**.